# Быстрая пакетная вставка в Firebird

Tags: sql, .net, firebird

Подскажите способ быстрой вставки в **Firebird** для `.NET`.
Необходимо загрузить в БД `~100` миллионов записей.

В **MS SQL** есть `SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy`.

В **Oracle** есть `ODP.NET`, поддерживающим Bulk Inserts за счет Array Binding.

Как быть с **Firebird**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте через внешние таблицы (с ручным отключением триггеров, индексов, FK прочих констренйнтов):

```sql
CREATE TABLE ext1 EXTERNAL 'c:\myfile.txt' 
(
field1 char(20),
field2 smallint
);

INSERT INTO realtable1 (field1, field2)
SELECT field1, field2 FROM ext1;
```

http://www.firebirdfaq.org/faq209/

Comment: насколько я понимаю, файл с данными в таком случае должен быть доступен на сервере/сети

Comment: @Ice2burn да, это локальный путь на сервере.

Comment: в текущей реализации вставка идет с клиента, видимо придется переписывать на уровень сервиса...